# React-Router. Props.children null

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

Здравствуйте. Прошу вашей помощи. Все уже перепробовал.

Использую React, Redux.

Один из дочерних компонентов(ClientDatas.jsx) ожидает this.props.children.
Пробую передать ему компонент на рендеринг через роут. Но в this.props вообще ничего не приходит.

```
//index.jsx
...
ReactDOM.render(
<Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>

        <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <IndexRoute component={Chat} />
            <Route component={ClientDatas}>
                <Route component={Test2} />
            </Route>
        </Route>

    </Router>
</Provider>,
document.getElementById("app"));

//ClientDatas.jsx
...
export default class ClientDatas extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {
                 this.props.children
            }
        </div>
    );
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ответов в Гугле не нашёл. Долго решал эту задачу. Лично на мой взгляд это выглядит как антипаттерн. Но иного решения мне найти не удалось.

В общем суть в том что нужно сначала инициализировать внутренний компонент(Chat.jsx), затем когда в нем уже будут данные отрендерить его как компонент по умолчанию в App.

```
<Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>

        <Route path="/" component={Chat}>
            <IndexRoute component={Test2} />
            <Route path="elemsone" component={Test2} />
            <Route path="elemstwo" component={Test3} />
        </Route>

        <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <IndexRoute component={Chat} />
        </Route>


        <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
    </Router>
</Provider>
```